# how to create osgi bundle from jar

Tags: osgi-bundle, apache-httpcomponents, karaf

I am using MultipartbodyBuilder to send file and metadata from a REST web service client. To use

In my pom file I have added

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and also

```
<Embed-Dependency>
  http-mime
</Embed-Dependency>
```

I have not added any bundle related to mime to this feature in the applications feature.xml

When I try to install the feature on karaf I get the following error in log files and it goes in Waiting

```
->net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.StackOverflowError-->null
2016-08-03 20:10:22,456[SpringOsgiExtenderThread-58]|ERROR|org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean|175-org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.7.3|net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException : java.lang.RuntimeException-->net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.StackOverflowError-->null
```

I am using karaf osgi so I figured that I need to have a osgi bundle mapped to features.xml http mime is a jar without any bundle. There is a httpclient osgi bundle but it has other dependencies and it breaks my other projects mapped in features xml.

I want to know how to create an osgi bundle using httpmime 4.3.2 jar file. I am new to this so if some guidance and reference will help.

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you can provide a meaningful title, and clarify what you're trying to do. As well, you should tag your question with a specific language.

Answer (score 0):

There is a karaf feature called wrap. This allows you to use also non OSGI jar files. In your feature.xml you just need to add the following `bundle` to your feature.

```
<bundle>wrap:mvn:org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/4.3.2</bundle>
```

Comment: Still get the same error        `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean|175-org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.7.3|net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean|175-org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.7.3|net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException : java.lang.StackOverflowError-->null
|org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean|175-org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs->net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.StackOverflowError-->null`

Comment: Sorry I just answered your question about how to get an OSGI plugin from an existing jar. I didn't look into the error and why it is happening.